# Loading animation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to validate some form fields. I have detected that the response from the server takes some seconds, and I would include some kind of animation that should indicate that the validation is not yet finished.

This is the JavaScript I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log("principio");
//control de alias
    $("#alias").keyup(function(){

        var ID=$("#alias").val();
        var REST=$("#rest").val();

        $.post("check_username.php", { username: ID, rest: REST},

                function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                    //if the result is 1
                    if(result == 1){

                        document.getElementById('mensajealias').innerHTML ="Alias disponible";
                          document.getElementById('boton').style.visibility='visible'; // hide 
                             document.getElementById('mensajeboton').innerHTML ="Ahora puede insertar los datos";
                    }else{
                          document.getElementById('mensajealias').innerHTML ="Alias no disponible";
                           document.getElementById('boton').style.visibility='hidden'; // hide 
                             document.getElementById('mensajeboton').innerHTML ="No se puede insertar hasta que no modifique los datos";
                        exit;
                    }
            });
    });
//control de rest
    $("#rest").change(function(){
        var ID=$("#alias").val();
        var REST=$("#rest").val();

        $.post("check_username.php", { username: ID, rest: REST},
                function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                    //if the result is 1
                    if(result == 1){
                        document.getElementById('mensajealias').innerHTML ="Alias disponible";    
                        document.getElementById('boton').style.visibility='visible'; // hide 
                        document.getElementById('mensajeboton').innerHTML ="Ahora puede insertar los datos";

                    }else{

                          document.getElementById('mensajealias').innerHTML ="Alias no disponible";
                           document.getElementById('boton').style.visibility='hidden'; // hide 
                             document.getElementById('mensajeboton').innerHTML ="No se puede insertar hasta que no modifique los datos";
                        exit;
                    }
            });
    });
//control de nombre
    $("#nombre_mesero").keyup(function(){
        var Nombre=$("#nombre_mesero").val();
    });    
});
</script>
```

I would like to show the animation for the two functions: `$("#alias").keyup(function()` and `$("#rest").change(function()`

Any advice to do it is very welcome. Thank you.

QUESTION EDITED

I have included the following code just below `$(document).ready(function(){`

```
/ Setup the ajax indicator
  $('body').append('<div id="ajaxBusy"><p><img src="wait.gif"></p></div>');

  $('#ajaxBusy').css({
    display:"none",
    margin:"0px",
    paddingLeft:"0px",
    paddingRight:"0px",
    paddingTop:"0px",
    paddingBottom:"0px",
    position:"absolute",
    right:"3px",
    top:"3px",
     width:"auto"
  });
```

I have also included the code:

```
    // Ajax activity indicator bound to ajax start/stop document events
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){ 
  $('#ajaxBusy').show(); 
}).ajaxStop(function(){ 
  $('#ajaxBusy').hide();
});
```

Now, every time the user enters a character in the field $("#alias"), the animation starts and  finishes when the event finishes, but after the seventh character the animation doesn't stop anymore....

Comment: I don't see any animations!

Comment: @AminJafari, that is exactly what am I asking for, how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Use `ajaxStart()` and `ajaxComplete()` to load and unload an animation.

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle of your code. Thx

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I have updated my question with a code proposal and an issue with it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to start with something like http://www.dzyngiri.com/show-loading-image-while-the-website-loads/
instead of page load, bind it to your events and disable it when response comes back.
start with some code and then ask if its not working instead of asking for example.

Comment: I have updated my question with a code proposal and an issue with it. Thank you.

Comment: did you check if your ajax request got the response that seventh time? you also need to mention what did you debug and found out.
apart from that, first off, you dont want to do it like this. there has to be some delay before you send request to check for username availability and also, dont send request unless atleast 3 characters or more.
you might be better off with using some sample code from other place.
post some working example that others can refer to to help you out because as such, its not much of debugging information given by  you.

Comment: It is solved now, thank you. There was an exit line in the second result condition that I have removed, it is working.